# best way to search and print the specific block of strings from file?

Tags: java

what is the best way to print the specific lines of strings from file?

for example:
file.txt

```
Id    : 123
car   : toyota
model : 1998

Id  : 129
car : merecdes
model :2007
```

at console:
Enter ID to search specific car and model:
123

ID : 123
 car: Toyota
 model : 1998

code:
/* skipped the "write file" portion of the code */
trying to implement: "Read the id and print car and name" according to the example

```
File mfile = new File("Employee.txt");
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(mfile);
         int firstline=0; //
         String thisLine = null;

         LineNumberReader m = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(mfile));
//       LineNumberReader lnr = new  LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("Employee"))); 
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(m);

         while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            /* myEmployee.getID();
             myEmployee.getName();
             myEmployee.getAge();
             */
             String line = scan.nextLine();// check next line
             String  s = null;
             firstline++;

             if(firstline==1)
             {
                 System.out.println(line);
                 String line2 = scan.nextLine();
                 firstline++;
                 if(s== "Name"){
                     System.out.println(line2);
                 }



             }
         }
         scan.close();
```

Comment: i guess one of the good ways is trying some code.

Comment: i implemented the logic and used this: but only could able to print ID.

Comment: then show us some code

Comment: @user3440716, this purely depends on how your sample data exists in the file. if you are sure that each record is separated by blank line. that's the logic you can go on with

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code: //the code is self-explanatory.

```
while(EOF) {
   String data = readLine();
   if(data.contains(inputId)) {
       //here record gets started
       System.out.println(data);
       String recordData;
       while((recordData = readLine()) != '\n'){
           System.out.println(recordData)
       }
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the line first. Then by using **split()** method you ca get what you want.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Read {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("someFile"));
            try {
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    if(line.contains("String 1")) {
                        // ...
                    } else if (line.contains("String 2")) {
                        // ...
                    }               
                    line = br.readLine();
                    String[] columns = line.split(" ");
                    System.out.println("ID: "+ columns[0] );
                    System.out.println("Car : "+ columns[1] );
                    System.out.println("Model : "+ columns[2] );
                }       
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am confused at if-else portion what should i do in order to dismiss next ID. The logic which i am trying to do is that when user types input as id, it should search that "id" and then print all 3 lines that is ID, name, model.

Comment: Take a scanner class. Use nextInt() to retrieve the next ID. Then again use split. Try to utilize your mind

Answer (score 0):

First of all, may I know if the file format could be change? All things would become simple if the records are stored like:
Id,car,model
123,toyota,1988
129,merecdes,2007
if not, then ignore this point...

I think you could use a HashMap to store the car info by reading every 4 lines, then you can get a single car by HashMap.get(Id).

Comment: no no i am trying to search id then print id,name,car. hashing would require longer method for me.